# Using deep index paths in UICollectionView data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am trying to back my UICollectionView's data source with a data structure that (for good reasons) is more than two layers deep. In other words, my data can be broken into sections, but not all of those sections simply contain items. Some contain *arrays* of items (or "nested sections", so to speak). These items can be easily be referenced with an index path *three* indices long (3.2.4, for instance), but UICollectionView's data source methods only seem to support index paths up to *two* indices long.

All of the UICollectionView APIs use NSIndexPaths to reference collection view items, so in theory they should work with any number of indices. The challenge is getting the collection view to "know" to ask for cells, layout attributes, etc. for items at these deeper indices when the data source protocol only provides `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and
`numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` to specify the indices it needs to ask for.

Is there any way around this that doesn't require me to (a) subclass UICollectionView, which [Apple explicitly discourages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html) (second point under "Tips for Implementing Your Custom Layouts") or (b) flatten my data structure, which would be less than ideal, and which seems unnecessarily limited given the APIs UICollectionView already provides?

Comment: Do you need these third levels to also be confined in their own sections, or could you just expose all items in the 2nd and 3rd level as part of the 1st level section?

Comment: Is the dataSource not laid out in a known fashion? If you could determine if the next object is an array, can you not programatically parse it and find the correct index path with if() blocks?  I can see where this would be a problem if you get data that has unknown structure

Comment: @JustinAmberson I think the issue there is that UICollectionView's data source methods won't ever be called asking about the deeper-nested indices, meaning he wouldn't be able to actually do said parsing. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Too late to edit I guess. The collectionView only knows that it has a section and items to go in the section. It seems like your data source doesn't line up with how the collection view works. I'd recommend flattening it like you say, but in a temporary instance variable or property somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make logical sense in the scheme of a standard collectionView (or tableView) to have a three tier index. I've seen some cool tableviews that have "expanding" cells that work in the same way you're describing. It's just that the object representing the expanding cell tells the table that it has multiple items available.

I can't understand how your collectionView is supposed to look as an end product. If you are encountering arrays at some index paths, what are you trying to represent? I don't want to inform your design but why not just show one item at that particular index, and when a user selects it, expand or show another view with those subsequent items?

Comment: My collection view contains different stacks of items that each need to be individually moveable and have their own layout attributes (in other words, I can't just make the stacks into the collection view items), but the stacks are also grouped into sections in different parts of the screen. Sorry I can't really be more specific than that.  

For now I'm just going to go ahead and flatten it such that each stack is a "section" of the collection view and manage the grouping of those stacks myself. Thanks for the "expanding" idea—it's just not what my app's functionality calls for in this case.